# Pod install PayPalMPL results in empty pod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, paypal-mpl

I've created a new sample iOS project and this pod file:

```
target 'PayPalSample' do
  pod 'PayPalMPL', '~> 2.1'
end
```

After executing "pod install" I get this output:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing PayPalMPL (2.1.7)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use 
`PayPalSample.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 
total pod installed.

[!] Automatically assigning platform ios with version 10.3 on target 
PayPalSample because no platform was specified. Please specify a 
platform for this target in your Podfile. See 
`https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

When I open op the workspace file, and have a look inside the Pods/Pods/PayPalMPL folder it is empty.

Am I missing something?
Thanks a lot!